# Loops and arrays not following through

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
int [] f = {1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1};
int [] b = {6,1};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hide(f,b)));

public static int [] hide(int [] front, int [] back) {
    int temp;
    int extraTemp;
    int nextTemp = 0;

    int [] hiddenAt = new int[front.length];
    //int [] shownAt = new int[front.length];

    for(int x = 0; x < front.length; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y <= back.length; y++){
            temp = x;
            if ((back.length > front.length) || (front[x] < 0 || back[y] < 0) || (front.length < 1 || back.length < 1)) {
                System.exit(0);
            }

            if (y < back.length - 1){
            nextTemp = Math.abs(back[y + 1] - front[x + 1]);
            }
            else {
                nextTemp = 0;
            }

            if (front[x] > back[y]) {
                System.out.println(temp);
            }
            else if (front[x] < back[y] && y >= back.length - 1 ) {
                extraTemp = back[y] - front[x];

                if (extraTemp > nextTemp){
                    extraTemp = nextTemp;
                }
                System.out.println(extraTemp);
            }
            else if (front[x] < back[y]) {
                extraTemp = back[y] - front[x];

                if (extraTemp > nextTemp){
                    extraTemp = nextTemp;
                }
                System.out.println(extraTemp);
            }
        }
    }
    return hiddenAt;
}
```

The `println`'s are being substituted in to see the values that are being produced. They will be `hiddenAt[z] = temp;` when I figure out the values to be correct.

I need it to compare `front[0]` with `back[0]` then `front[1]` with `back[1]`, etc. After that, it will shift over one: `front[1]` with `back[1]` then `front[2]` with `back[2]` until the end of `front[]`. I want to find out where the lowest difference is. (In this case when the number in the []'s is 4 and 5.)

I get two errors, one saying line 39
        if ((back.length > front.length) || (front[x] < 0 || back[y] < 0) || (front.length < 1 || back.length < 1)) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }

is wrong and that line 9 is wrong as well.
    public class 2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int [] f = {1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1};
    int [] b = {6,1};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hide(f,b)));
}
```

the exact error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at hw2.hide(hw2.java:39)
at hw2.main(hw2.java:9)
```

Comment: not really sure what your question is! There should be something in your post that has a question mark in it :P

Comment: What is the output that you are getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: I'm getting an error but I want a printed array of {-4, -5} (the numbers corresponding to the index number on the front array where the difference between the two is minimized) the negative signs just mean that the difference there is NOT 0.

Comment: While `else if (front[x] < back[y] && y >= back.length - 1 )` should not throw an exception, it's kinda strange: how `y` can become **more** than `back.length-1`?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Array index out of bounds so you are trying to access an element that doesn't exist.

in the line
    if ((back.length > front.length) || (front[x] < 0 || back[y] < 0) || (front.length < 1 || back.length < 1)) {
where you say  `back[y] < 0` your for statement goes to `<= back.length`

```
for(int y = 0; y <= back.length; y++){
```

so back has a length of 2(has 2 elements) however you will be doing this loop three times 0,1,2 on the third loop there is no `back[2]` as `back[0] = 6` and `back[1] = 1` .

so changing  `for(int y = 0; y <= back.length; y++){` to `for(int y = 0; y < back.length; y++){` will fix this particular error

Remember, lengths start at 1(if it has elements) indexes start at 0.

Comment: This creates a different error in the line (     nextTemp = Math.abs(back[y + 1] - front[x + 1]);)

Comment: @user2449907 - This **reveals** another error. It was there all along.

Comment: May I ask, why when I make changes... it no longer increases the x and y at the same time so it's not comparing the right elements?

Comment: because you have nested for loops, they never increase at the same time. Try debugging your program and stepping through it.

Answer (score 0):

This is your **2nd** array problem:

```
        if (y < back.length - 1){
        nextTemp = Math.abs(back[y + 1] - front[x + 1]);
        }
        else {
            nextTemp = 0;
        }
```

While you check that `y < back.length - 1` you do **not** do the same for `x`.

So, you need `if (y < back.lenth-1 && x < front.length-1)` assuming that you do want to reference `front[x+1]`.